# How can I create a webserver in C which supports PHP pages?

Tags: php, c, sockets, webserver

First of all, I know to create web servers which deal with static html pages.

I want to create a **web server which supports PHP pages.**

I have coded a server like below,
`-> main()` function just create a socket, accept a request and calls connection(fd) function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     if (argc < 2) {
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
         error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd, 5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     /*
      Server runs forever, forking off a separate
      process for each connection.
      */
     while (1) {
          newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
          if (newsockfd < 0)
             error("ERROR on accept");
          pid = fork();

          if (pid < 0)
              error("ERROR on fork");
          if (pid == 0) {
               close(sockfd);
               connection(newsockfd);
               exit(0);
          } else
            close(newsockfd);
     } /* end of while */
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; /* we never get here */
}
```

`-> connection()` function sets document root, and explicitly sets a PHP page(echo.php)  and calls php-cgi() function. php-cgi() does the further process.

Actually i dont know what php5-cgi does. When i run the server and request a page from web browser, it shows "Am a PHP file"  for 1 second, and hides, displays the message,

> The connection was reset

1) What is the proper way to handle php pages in web server

2) Can anyone suggest me some books or anything to develop a web server in                                                 C which handle PHP pages?

3) Do i wanna try any other language? which is the most preferable language to create web server and proxies?

4) how to deal with query strings and POST method requests?

when i did telnet to the server it works,

```
GET /echo.php HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<body>
Am a PHP file
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: php has built-in web server. to run simple web server, you can run this command from command prompt `php -S localhost:80`

Comment: but HOW CAN I create a webserver like apache? dont want much security, but it should execute PHP scripts. how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some HTTP header fields. One of the problems is that the browser doesn't know how much data to expect; so while it receives and parses data the connection is closed because your PHP script ends and the browser goes "Huh?".

So, you must send either a Content-length header (if you know the length of your body in advance) or a Transfer-encoding field (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). The first solution adds another problem: you must determine the lenght before sending the headers. This would mean capturing all output in a buffer, counting the bytes, then send the header(s) followed by the content. But that would add another fork() to your code... I tried adding a header like `Transfer-Encoding: identity` but that didn't work well. You may want to add a `Connection: close` header as well.

Your other questions are a bit broad; it doesn't matter which language you use, you will have to do all the hard work of parsing HTTP request headers, assembling headers, forking, parsing parameters, etc. Your approach with fork(), execl() is theoretically sound but requires a lot more work. So yeah, using Apache, nginx or any other webserver sounds tempting to use...

Comment: thanks. but now i want to know. How the PHP scripts  execute in server. Is that the same way i did using ph5-cgi script. where can i found the documentations to implement that?

Comment: when i start a child process using, execl("/usr/bin/php5-cgi", "php5-cgi", NULL);     it directly talk to browser with 2 headers:- X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
Content-Type: text/html.                                                                   
It doese not send the last "\r\n\r\n" to separate the headers from the entity body. Am i right? How can i add that. i think am close, can you please help me.

Comment: when i did telnet to the server i got the working result,       GET /echo.php HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<body>
Am a PHP file
</body>
</html>

Comment: I don't think there are documents that describe exactly how to call the php5-cgi script; you may want to look in the sources of the PHP Apache module (which are part of the PHP sources). And as you pointed out, the php5-cgi binary already adds some headers lines. Which makes your job even more complicated, because you have to read the output from the executable, read the headers (possibly modify them), then start processing the body of the output, add your own headers and THEN send the body. You may actually want to try the popen() call instead of execl().

Comment: i understood. now i have a doubt, to pass query string for GET request i caould use  " putenv("QUERY_STRING="); " , So to pass POST request parameters , which ENVIRONMENT variable do i need to set??

Comment: and can you pls say, what is the effect of this code:  dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);   ,  when i comment this i got html output in terminal only. not send to browser. I know it duplicate the fd, but when i give this how it would redirect to browser?

Comment: The man page of dup2 is a bit non-intuitive, but you're essentially redirecting the standard output of your program to 'fd', the filedescriptor of your socket. (STDOUT_FILENO is macro that refers to the file descriptor of standard out). dup2() closes STDOUT_FILENO so the output does not appear in the terminal anymore, and what used to to be STDOUT_FILENO replaced with fd.

Comment: Can you please say, How can i send "Cookie/PHPSESSID" to php5-cgi from my server to maintain session.??